# Are Upanishads religous texts?

Tags: upanishads

Are Upanishads religious texts ? Or Are they "philosophical" texts ? Does it contains words of gods ?
I have hear that Upnishads are just words of teachers of ancient India, who during free time told these things to the students. And It was noted down and it became Upanishads.

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Philosophical texts are written by humans. Religious texts are written by God , spoken by God , stories about God.

Comment: Upanishad - where a student comes and sits near the guru (upanishidati) to learn about God, it is called an Upanishad. Eg. In Kathopanishad, Nachiketa approaches Yama. Brihadaranyaka has Yajnavalkya teaching his wife, etc. now you decide where to categorise this.

Comment: The different upanishads are lifted directly from the vedas. Vyasa did the classification of pulling different sections of the vedas into what is referred to as the various upanishads. Do you consider the vedas religious texts or philosophical texts? The difference between a religious text and a philosophical text is a modern western difference - there is no difference between a religious text and a philosophical text in Hinduism.

Comment: @river can you give a few examples of Religious texts that are written by God, spoken by God, stories about God? that are not written by humans?

Comment: According to Srivaishnavites and Madhwists, ALL Upanishads are Bhakti texts to Vishnu, regardless of whether any deity-name occurs in them @river

Comment: Learnt after learning All Angas of Rig, Yajur, Sama & Atharva. That is, AFTER you have mastery of the recital & intonations of all the above Shastras in a School for young Brahmachari (celibate), Brahmin Trainees - to perform rituals, You have to master the intonations of 'Upanishath' or 'sit-next-to' sessions. So, Yes, It is religious. 
Next, the content of such 'sit-next-to' instructions is Mainly Philosophical. For 'Brihatharanyaka' mastery - you are to resort to the quest for its meaning post-retirement in a Jungle(Aranyaka) after satisfying Family + other obligatory responsibilities.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking basic stuff